# How to access MSK (Kafka) from outside VPC

Tags: aws-msk

I have a VM which DC configured and able to access private ApiGateway, but while trying to access msk, throwing error.

I installed Kafka in my VM, and using Kafka topic command trying to create one topic inside AWS msk but it's not connecting. Security group for inbound is already configured for all traffic.

How can I connect the msk outside my VPC?

Comment: What error is thrown?

Comment: Can we ping /curl the kafka broker urls ?how I know that this url is going to conect from my vm ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it resolved, please check the security group for this, you need to allow your cidr block for that.